# Let field value set sort order direction in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-order-by

Given the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE `example` (
  `Identifier` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `FieldValue` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FieldOrder` enum('asc','desc') DEFAULT 'asc',
  PRIMARY KEY (`Identifier`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I want to run a query that sorts the FieldValue field based on the value in the FieldOrder field. E.g.

```
Select * from example order by FieldValue [here should the FieldOrder value be placed]
```

Is it possible to make a reference to the FieldOrder field in the sort by part of the query?

Comment: Question is not clear enough. Please add some example to show what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: How would this work if the table has two records; one saying it should be ascending, and one saying descending? Please provide examples...

Comment: What does `FieldValue` contain?  Does it happen to contain multiple values (comma-separated), maybe?  If so, do *not* store multiple values in one field.  Use a link table and "normalize" your database.

Comment: @Mr47 The value of FieldOrder is always the same. The underlaying data is grouped. Each group of records has it own sort order. However only one group is queried at a time.This example is just a very simplified version.

Comment: @Nebu: If only "group" is queried at a time, then this table structure is not correct.  What you really want is a table where you have multiple rows per group, each row containing a single value.  Then you just query gor the identifier and sort as you want.

Answer (score 2):

One way to approach this is to treat `FieldValue` as positive or negative for `FieldOrder` values of "asc" and "desc" respectively. This can be expressed by a `case` expression:

```
SELECT   *
FROM     example
ORDER BY CASE FieldOrder WHEN 'asc' THEN 1 ELSE -1 END * FieldValue
```

Comment: I didn't notice the fieldorder column while you nailed it :) +1

Comment: This works great for numeric values. Can you also provide a solution for letters values?

Answer (score 1):

Not that I know of ...

Please note that every row has a `FieldOrder` so what you seek to achieve seems to be questionable.  What if one row says `asc` and another row say `desc`?  How should the order of the two rows be shown then?

If you want to have parameterized `order by` action, you can consider using the following two methods:

1. Use a stored procedure that takes an argument for, say,
   `sortingOrder`
2. Use a programming language (e.g. Java) to construct a query string and
   inject the sorting order dynamically, and 
   then execute the query string to MySQL

Answer (score 0):

You need to normalize your data and store it in a better schema.  Do not store multiple values in a single field, only store one value per row.  What you can do is store the multiple data in its own table, where each piece of data is in its own row.

Try a schema like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `example` (
  `Identifier` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Identifier`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `exampleData` (
  `RowID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Identifier` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `FieldValue` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`RowID`),
  INDEX `Identifier` (`Identifier`),
  FOREIGN KEY (Identifier) REFERENCES example(Identifier)
  ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Now you have two tables, and in your `exampleData` table, you have *one* row per each piece of data in `FieldValue`.

Now you can query like so:

```
SELECT Identifier, FieldValue
FROM example
JOIN exampleData USING(Identifier)
WHERE Identifier = 3
ORDER BY FieldValue ASC
```